# Does the -O0 compiler flag have the same effect as the volatile keyword in C?

Tags: c, optimization, microcontroller, volatile

When you use the **-O0** compiler flag in C, you tell the compiler to avoid any kind of optimization. When you define a variable as `volatile`, you tell the compiler to avoid optimizing that variable. Can we use the two approaches interchangeably? And if so what are the pros and cons? Below are some pros and cons that I can think of. Are there any more?

**Pros:**

- Using the **-O0** flag is helpful if we have a big code base inside which the variables that should have been declared as `volatile`, are not. If the code is showing buggy behavior, instead of going in the code and finding which variables need to be declared as volatile, we can just use the **-O0** flag to eliminate the possibility that optimization is causing the problem.

**Cons:**

- The **-O0** flag will affect the entire code while the `volatile` keyword only affects a specific variable. If we're working on a small microcontroller for example, this could be a problem since using **-O0** may produce a big executable.

Comment: " we can just use the -O0 flag to eliminate the possibility that optimization is causing the problem"  Yes you can use this as debug technique to find the bug. But not as a bug fix.

Comment: @Lundin I thnk you're overstating the similarity between `volatile` and `-O0`.  It's not an optimization to read a variable once into a register and leave it there, using the value many, many times without re-reading it, or conversely keep updating that value in a register and only storing it once after many iterations of a loop.  Such behavior isn't something that `-O0` can be expected to prevent, but such behavior directly contradicts the very meaning of `volatile`.  Using `-O0` can be *useful* in identifying code issues, but it's nowhere near definitive or exhaustive.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Placing a variable in a register is an optimization by itself on most systems. Anyway, the kind of bugs the OP refer to are likely of the kind where a file scope variable is updated by an ISR or callback, but the main program does not realize that the variable has been changed, and therefore optimizes the code accordingly. That is a classic and very nasty bug, which you _can_ actually track down by disabling optimizations. A somewhat common real-world scenario would be: "why does the code break in release build but not debug build".

Comment: AFAIK the compiler is totally allowed to ignore any `-Ox` flags. What optimizations are done, or not done at each level is left for the compiler to decide, as long as the "as if" rule is followed. There is no guarantee that every variable becomes implicit `volatile`, unless the compiler documentation says so.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The short answer is: the `volatile` keyword does ***not*** mean "do not optimize". It is something completely different. It informs the compiler that the variable may be changed by something which is not visible for the compiler in the normal program flow. For example:

1. It can be changed by the hardware - usually registers mapped in the memory address space
2. Can be changed by the function which is never called - for example the interrupt routine
3. Variable can be changed by another process or hardware - for example shared memory in the multiprocessor / multicore systems

The volatile variable has to be read from its storage location every time it is used, and saved every time it was changed.

Here you have an example:

```
int foo(volatile int z)
{
    return z + z + z + z;
}

int foo1(int z)
{
    return z + z + z + z;    
}
```

and the resulting code (-O0 optimization option)

```
foo(int):
  push rbp
  mov rbp, rsp
  mov DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi
  mov edx, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
  mov eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
  add edx, eax
  mov eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
  add edx, eax
  mov eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
  add eax, edx
  pop rbp
  ret
foo1(int):
  push rbp
  mov rbp, rsp
  mov DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi
  mov eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
  sal eax, 2
  pop rbp
  ret
```

The difference is obvious I think. The volatile variable is read 4 times, non volatile is read once, then multiplied by 4.

You can play yourself here: https://godbolt.org/g/RiTU4g

In the most cases if the program does not run when you turn on the compiler optimization, you have some hidden UBs in your code. You should debug as long as needed to discover all of them. The correctly written program must run at any optimization level.

Bear in mind that `volatile' **does not** mean or guarantee the coherency & atomicity.

Comment: Good answer, I just wanted to add that any bugs that "go away" when using -O0 are probably not caused by the lack of a volatile keyword.   This behavior could be uninitialized variables, stack corruption, buffer overruns, etc.

Comment: The C standard does not agree, it says black on white that volatile means do not optimize. C11 5.1.2.3 "An actual implementation need not evaluate part of an expression if it can deduce that its
value is not used and that no needed side effects are produced (including any caused by calling a function or accessing a volatile object)." This text is the very core of the C language. Sure, volatile means other things too but it certainly means that any access to the variable is a side-effect.

Comment: @Lundin it does not mean do no optimize - this lack of the optimization implies from it proneness to the side effects. And this sentence means exactly that.

Comment: You forgot to mention two other use cases for `volatile`: communication with signal handlers, and changes that have to be visible after `setjmp/longjmp`.

Comment: @JensGustedt it is **"for example"**. There are much more usage cases.

Comment: The semantics of `volatile` are, to a significant extent, implementation-defined.  Quality implementations such as icc which are suitable for low-level programming even with optimizations enabled will treat the semantics more strongly than others like gcc which are not.

Answer (score 13):

Compiler flag `-O0` is in no way a replacement for proper use of `volatile`, because the code that does not work when it is properly optimized by the compiler is inherently broken. You do not want a broken code giving you an appearance of "working" until someone forgets to throw the `-O0` switch.

It is unusual even for large code bases to have a need for many volatile variables, in terms of the total percentage of variables in the code. Fixing a large code base with missing `volatile` is likely to require finding a few strategic places where multiple variables need to be `volatile`, and fixing just these few, rather than taking a "shotgun approach" and disabling all optimizations.

Comment: Actually there are very limited places where you need the volatile variable. As i wrote in my answer they are needed only if the variable is prone to the side effects.

Comment: It is incredibly common for small code bases to have lots of need for volatile. Namely in any program doing any form of hardware-related programming. This question is tagged "microcontroller", so it is safe to assume that the code base needs around 1000 volatile-qualified variables for the register map alone.

Comment: @Lundin Right, memory-mapped registers is what I meant when I wrote "a few strategic places [in code] where multiple variables need to be `volatile`".

Comment: Opening up a random, medium-sized embedded project of mine, approx 20kib size and 50kLOC, it contains the keyword `volatile` in 78 places, excluding the register map and register definitions. Pretty normal project.

Comment: @Lundin but it is still a very few - registers & shared memory & multi thread data (including the exception ones). I did not think about the number of the variables. BTW it is good to mention that volatile does not mean coherency & atomicity.

Comment: The Standard does not require that implementations be suitable for low-level programming.  With optimizations enabled, gcc processes an inferior dialect of C which is less suitable for such purposes than either the dialect processed with optimizations disabled, or the higher-quality dialect processed by icc with optimizations enabled.

Answer (score 4):

> Using the -O0 flag is helpful if we have a big code base inside which the variables that should have been declared as volatile, are not

You could use `O0` to *debug* and fix the problems in such cases.

> If the code is showing buggy behavior, instead of going in the code and finding which variables need to be declared as volatile, we can just use the -O0 flag to eliminate the possibility that optimization is causing the problem.

That's a wrong conclusion. There's no guarantee that `O0` "fixes" the problem due to some variable(s) missing `volatile` qualifier. The problem still exists in your code and needs to be fixed.

You seem to have misunderstood `volatile`. It's not something that controls compiler optimisation per se. Whereas [`O0`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) typically disables most optimisations (compiler can *still* optimize though).

In conclusion, no, they are totally different, serving different purposes. As such, there's no question of using one over other or using interchangeably.

There's no reason to disable compiler optimisations. You need to fix the problem in your code i.e, add `volatile` qualifiers to variable(s) that require it.

Comment: it's better to use `-Od` for debugging

Comment: @phuclv I think you mean `-Og`.

Comment: @JL2210 Yes, that's a typo

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers already cover volatile pretty well, but I believe the root cause of this question has nothing to do with volatile.

If your code works with -O0 but doesn't with optimizations enabled, you may have a wide variety of bugs in your code, or it is also possible that the compiler is buggy. This being tagged "microcontroller", I wouldn't rule out compiler bugs.

It's possible that you have a buffer overrun or underrun, for example, and the optimizer simply arranges your code in a slightly different way which exposes the bug. Try running your code through a static code analyzer (such as cppcheck or llvm's static code analysis). Whether that's a feasible option depends on how microcontroller-specific your code is, though.

Finally, depending on the compiler, -O0 might still generate code that keeps some value in a register for a while unless volatile is used, so I wouldn't call -O0 a replacement for volatile in any case. (That's compiler specific naturally).

Comment: More likely the code relies upon low-level constructs which quality compilers that are suitable for low-level programming (e.g. icc) can support with optimizations enabled, but which the authors of gcc take pride in not supporting except by disabling optimizations.